# Shutter Script(s)

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, x11

When I play some games with wine, I must not change the window, because of that, the game crash or that window are fill of black.

I'm using xfce4 desktop , when I press "PrintScreen" key from keyboard, this changes the window to "xfce4-screenshooter", and well I need take screenshots without ask me the filename I want to save it as.

I have installed "shutter", but I can use commands with the option "%NN" , because of that shutter show me an error or crash.

For example with:

```
shutter -f -e -n -o "$PWD/%NN_%d-%m-%Y-%T.png"
```

I want to make a simple script for save in somewhere with "Name_Number_Date"
something like

```
#!/bin/bash

HERE=$($PWD)
FOLDER="$HOME/Images/Shutter"
let COUNTER=0
NUMBER=$(($COUNTER+1))

cd "$FOLDER"

for COUNTER in $NUMERO do
    NUMBER=$(($CONTADOR+1))
    shutter -f -e -n -o "$FOLDER/"$NUMBER"_%d-%m-%Y.png" &
done
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use file matching operator in your `for` loop. `for f in *_*.png` will match all the png file names as you specified and assign each name to variable f. Then inside the loop use the `${f%_*}` bash operation to extract only the number of the file.

```
FOLDER="$HOME/Images/Shutter"
cd "$FOLDER"
for f in *_*.png
do
    num=${f%_*}
    shutter -f -e -n -o "${FOLDER}/${num}_$(date '+%d-%m-%Y.png')"
done
```

Comment: In the ${num} , how i can do "Incremetal Value" ????

Comment: increment like this: `numplus=$((num+1))`